# Covariance Question

Tags: covariance

$X$ and $Y$ are two independent variables, with variances $\sigma^2_x$ and $\sigma^2_y$ respectively.

Two other variables $W$ and $V$ are defined by $W=X+Y$ and $V=X-Y$.

Find $Cov(X,V)$ and $Cov(W,V)$

Comment: Hint: $\operatorname{Cov}(\bullet,\bullet)$ is bilinear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
Recall that covariance satisfies bilinearity,

$$\text{Cov}(aX+Y, Z) = a\text{Cov}(X,Z)+\text{Cov}(Y,Z)$$
and $$\text{Cov}(X,X) = \text{Var}(X).$$

Comment: So Cov(X,V)=Cov(X,X-Y)=Cov(2X)+Cov(X-Y)?

Comment: No, try again..

Comment: Sorry should the last term be -Cov(X,Y)?

Comment: No, try again..

Comment: Cov(X,X) - Cov(X,Y)?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I see now. Thank you very much

Comment: @ItsImpulse No problem. Considering giving up votes and [check marks](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to respondents in all your posts. Good luck.